# How does Gradle find a setings.gradle file

Tags: gradle

In a normal project, I can have a structure like this:

```
myProject/
    build.gradle
    gradle.properties
    **settings.gradle**
```

but if I have another project

```
myProject2/
    build.gradle
    gradle.properties
```

it works fine.

Things go strange when myProject2 is a subfolder (but not sub-project) of myProject.

```
myProject/
    myProject2/
        build.gradle
        gradle.properties
    build.gradle
    gradle.properties
    settings.gradle
```

**How does gradle find what *settings* file to use?**

Comment: How do things "go strange?"

Comment: @Cinch myProject2 seems to use the settings.gradle file of the parent directory, instead of nothing (which i would expect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `settings.gradle` file has the next 2 main purposes:

1. Add libraries to your build script classpath
2. Define which projects are taking part in the multi-project build

Therefore it is optional for a single-project build but due to #2 it is mandatory for multi-project builds.

By default it is assumed that the location of the settings file is also the location of the root project but you can redefine the location of the root project in the settings file.

Now, gradle logic for locating `settings.gradle` file as documented in gradle user guide **[here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)**:

> If you trigger a multiproject build from a directory with a settings
>   file, things are easy [**Amnon** - you just found it]...
>
> If you execute Gradle from within a project with no settings.gradle file, Gradle looks for a settings.gradle file in the following way:
>
> - It looks in a directory called master which has the same nesting level
>     as the current dir.
> - If not found yet, it searches parent directories.
> - If not found yet, the build is executed as a single project build. If
>     a settings.gradle file is found, Gradle checks if the current project
>     is part of the multiproject hierarchy defined in the found
>     settings.gradle file.
> - If not, the build is executed as a single
>     project build. Otherwise a multiproject build is executed. Otherwise
>     (you executed Gradle from

(Gradle user guide also provides the purpose of this behavior **[here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:initialization)**).

Now, back to your case, the first two project layouts you provided are for a single project build so `settings.gradle` is optional. For your third project layout if you'll run gradle from the root project (myProject) then it will find `settings.gradle` next to it but if you'll run it from `myProject2` folder then since this project parent path contains a `settings.gradle` file, gradle will find it and use it.

Comment: Great. I couldn't find the docs that said it searched parent directories.

Comment: @wrossmck https://docs.gradle.org/4.0.1/userguide/build_lifecycle.html  Initialization

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere but do you know, how far up the parent directories does gradle look for the `settings.gradle file`? For example does it search on the immediate parent directory only? Or goes to the parent directory of parent directory, and so on till it finds the `settings.gradle` file? @Amnon